# Remembering angular position in a stepper motor

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, robotics

I am looking for suggestions about how to define an initial position for a motor so that I can keep track of my current angular position relative to that point. I am using a stepper motor so to move to a given angle I count steps. I currently have a function that fakes a sort of PWM signal and moves a motor THROUGH a given angle at a certain speed and direction. It looks like this:

```
def RotMotor(SPIN, DPIN, direction, degrees, speed):
    GPIO.output(DPIN, direction)
    #For precise control the number of steps required to move to a given angle 
    #is calculated by the following line of code
    num_steps = (float(degrees) / float(360)) * 800
    #The sleep time is derived from the input RPM by converting RPM to time 
    #between each step
    sleeptime = 1 / ((float(speed) * 800) / 60)
    print('Taking ' + str(num_steps) + ' steps at ' + str(speed) + ' RPM.')
    #This while loop will take the calulated number of steps and count each 
    #step the motor makes in moving to its next point
    while num_steps > 0:
        GPIO.output(SPIN, 1)
        #The sleep function is called twice (High duration + Low Duration)
        time.sleep(sleeptime / 2)
        GPIO.output(SPIN, 0)
        #Second call of sleep function. Sleep function 1 + Sleep function 2 = 
        #Time for One Step
        time.sleep(sleeptime / 2)
        #Count 1 step
        num_steps -= 1
```

What I am trying to do is develop a way that I can feed this function a list of positions so that it will:

1.) Know that where it started from is zero
   2.) Know that if it's at 90 degrees and it is told to go to 180 then it 
       moves 90 degrees.

Earlier I said my function will move THROUGH the angle. My objective is to move TO the angle. Then when my list ends it will go back to zero without be having to include that coordinate in the list.

I have a vague idea of what I need to do but am very open to suggestion at this point. Thanks for any feedback.

Answer (score -1):

I came up with a simple solution for those of you who were interested in this question. Rather than explain I am just going to post the code here for anyone to try.

```
'''
This code is used to drive two NEMA 17 stepper motors both driven by their own A4988 
driver circuit. The step resolution is set to 1/4 steps, which results in 800 steps 
per revolution for this specific motor. If you use this code be sure to change the number 
800 anywhere in this code to your own motors steps per revolution.
'''
#!/usr/bin/env python

#Importing all relevant packages

import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import numpy
import time

#Defining GPIO setup (STEP PINS (odd) AND DIRECTION PINS (even) FOR EACH MOTOR)

PINS = [11, 12, 15, 16]
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(PINS, GPIO.OUT)

#Initialize a list that stores the amount of steps taken for each coordinate for the duration of the program

mem1 = [0]
mem2 = [0]

#Function to tell a motor how to move based on direction (CW / CCW), how many degrees to move, and what speed to move at (RPM)
#For precise control the number of steps required to move to a given angle is calculated by the following line of code

def RotMotor(SPIN, DPIN, direction, degrees, speed, memory):
    pos = sum(memory)
    num_steps = ((float(degrees) / float(360)) * 800) - pos
    memory.append(num_steps)
    if num_steps < 0:
        x = abs(num_steps)
        dir = GPIO.output(DPIN, 1)
    else:
        x = num_steps
        GPIO.output(DPIN, 0)
    sleeptime = 1 / ((float(speed) * 800) / 60)
    print('Taking ' + str(num_steps) + ' steps at ' + str(speed) + ' RPM.')
    while x > 0:
        GPIO.output(SPIN, 1)
        time.sleep(sleeptime / 2)
        GPIO.output(SPIN, 0)
        time.sleep(sleeptime / 2)
        x -= 1

#THE FOLLOWING LINES ARE QUICK CODE FOR TESTING.

Motor1Ins = []
Motor2Ins = []

angles = [45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315, 360, 315, 270, 225, 180, 135, 90, 45, 0]

for i in angles:
   Motor1Ins.append([11, 12, i, 20, mem1])
   Motor2Ins.append([15, 16, i, 20, mem2])

try:
   while True:
      for s, d, theta, t, MotMem in Motor1Ins:
         RotMotor(s, d, theta, t, MotMem)
         time.sleep(0.5)
      for s, d, theta, t, MotMem in Motor2Ins:
         RotMotor(s, d, theta, t, MotMem)
         time.sleep(0.5)
except KeyboardInterrupt():
   RotMotor(11, 12, 0, 20, mem1)
   RotMotor(15, 16, 0, 20, mem2)

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Essentially, I created a list that acts as memory then used some logic to decide how the motion should work based on what it remembers. I think I should write to a file somewhere else and then replace the current memory value rather than allow the list to continuously grow for memory reasons but this works for now.